# How to make 3D camera zoom with c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d, camera, zooming

So basically i wrote this code:

```
int zoom = 20;
int normal = 31;
float smooth = 5;

private bool isZoomed = false;
private bool notZoomed = false;

void Update()
{

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift))
    {
        isZoomed = !isZoomed;
    }

    if (isZoomed)
    {
        GetComponent<Camera>().fieldOfView = Mathf.Lerp(GetComponent<Camera>().fieldOfView, zoom, Time.deltaTime * smooth);
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.LeftShift))
    {
        notZoomed = !notZoomed;
    }

    if (notZoomed)
    {
        GetComponent<Camera>().fieldOfView = Mathf.Lerp(GetComponent<Camera>().fieldOfView, normal, Time.deltaTime * smooth);
    }
}
```

This is for a smooth zoom but it doesn't works very well, is full of bugs ecc.. 
I want to do a similar "minecraft Optifine Zoom" (basically when i keep shift pressed it zoom and if i realease shift it come back to the normal camera fov) Please can somebody fix my code or send me another one? Pls i really need it. Thanks <3

Comment: no we can't fix your code you need to tell us what is the error. "is full of bugs" dont really help. did you debug it ?

Answer (score 0):

first off you need to only use a single bool value for you if statements and you can then you an if else on a single boolean. Currently are toggling 2 different Booleans on press and release, but neither simultaneously.

Your other issue is with the use of lerp, specifically the final parameter. Essentially you will never be able to reach your target zoom field of view because your calculation should never result in 1.

For smoothly transitioning you should store a float to use as a lerp value

```
float lerp = 0f;
void Update()
{

if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift))
{
    isZoomed = !isZoomed;
}

if (isZoomed)
{
    lerp = Mathf.Max( Time.deltaTime * smooth + lerp, 1f);
    GetComponent<Camera>().fieldOfView = Mathf.Lerp(normal, zoom, lerp);
} else {
    lerp = Mathf.Min( Time.deltaTime * smooth - lerp 1f);
   GetComponent<Camera>().fieldOfView = Mathf.Lerp(normal, zoom, lerp);
}

if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.LeftShift))
{
    isZoomed = !isZoomed;
}
```

}